# WP-eCommerce: Getting products based on two categories (return a products that only exist within both categories)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I just started developing in Wordpress, specifically with the WP-eCommerce plugin and I've run into several issues. One of the primary issues is the ability to query specific products based on it's existence within two (or more) categories. In this instance, I would like the only products returned to be those that exist in both categories but not just one or the other.

I understand that this can be done on my own (raw php) or with just wp_query (or something alike this). However, I would like to stay within the WP-eCommerce framework as much as possible so as to limit the amount of styling and redundant code required.

For some clarification, an example of this situation would be as such:

query string sent to url - `http://example.com/?wpsc_product_category=cat1&wpsc_product_category=cat2`

This then gets sent and processed by WP-eCommerce but only takes the most recent `wpsc_product_category` query, and as a result only returns products that exist within cat2.

So, in conclusion my two primary questions are:

1. What sort of options are available to me within the WP-eCommerce framework that would allow me to make a query and return a product that exists in both and not just one of the categories.

   - if that isn't possible, what sort of wordpress options are available to me
   - what about creating my own function?
2. What exactly is the query process within WP-eCommerce. In the least, I could possibly access the file that formats the query string and get it to query both categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved with the significant help of a colleague of mine.

Basically, as wpecommerce is structured, it designs the `WP-Query` to only really manage one variable to search by. In order to circumvent this you need to override the `$wp_query` variable either in your own function, the file you wish to have multiple queries, etc.

This was done by utilizing code found from the wordpress codex [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

Excerpt:

```
 $args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'movie_genre',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array( 'action', 'comedy' )
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'actor',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => array( 103, 115, 206 ),
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    )
)
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

With some modification this allowed me to access the different taxonomy variable relationships directly and string together multiple search variables.

Answer (score 1):

So then, if somebody wanted to create a loop based on two product categories, say "Soon" and "Skinny", this should work?  Its giving me all the results from the first category still.. am I missing something?

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'wpsc-product',
    'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',   
        'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'Soon'
        ),  
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'Skinny'
        )
    )
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
```

Comment: A few things to suggest, although I can't be entirely sure because I haven't seen how you set up your wpecommerce. Are both taxonomies categories? is one a variation? If so, the taxonomies mite be different (wpsc_product_category and wpsc-variation)? Another thing to consider is to try inputting the id of the terms instead of names, see what happens there. I also like my field to be id based, in that case.